# SQL query - IF and ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `dbo.VBAK` with columns `VKORG, VBELN and SPART`

How do I write query below correctly

```
If dbo.tblVBAK.VKORG = '1001' 
BEGIN
   select dbo.tblVBAK.VKORG as 'Sales Org Approved' from dbo.tblVBAK
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   Select dbo.tblVBAK.VKORG as 'Sales Org Not Approved' from dbo.tblVBAK
END
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Which MS product you use?

Comment: Please provide a sample output.  How many columns do you need?

Comment: How you expecting that different values of `VKORG` will be under column name '_Sales Org Approved_'. If in result set rows will keep both values..?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN VKORG = '1001' 
       THEN 'Sales Org Approved' 
       ELSE 'Sales Org NOT Approved' 
       END,
       VBELN,
       SPART
FROM   dbo.tblVBAK
```

If you want to have them on different columns then:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN VKORG = '1001' 
       THEN VKORG
       END AS 'Sales Org Approved',
       CASE 
       WHEN VKORG <> '1001' 
       THEN VKORG
       END AS 'Sales Org Not Approved',
       VBELN,
       SPART
FROM   dbo.tblVBAK
```

Comment: @FabienTheSolution I have provided an updated solution. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Miss a comma after the "not approved" :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN VKORG = '1001' THEN VKORG ELSE NULL END as 'Sales Org Approved',
 CASE WHEN VKORG != '1001' THEN VKORG ELSE NULL END as 'Sales Org Not Approved'
FROM tblVBAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be done with a `UNION` :

```
SELECT VKORG AS 'Sales Org Approved', 
       null AS 'Sales Org Not Approved', 
       VBELN,
       SPART
FROM tblVBAK
WHERE VKORG = '1001'
UNION ALL
SELECT null AS 'Sales Org Approved', 
       VKORG AS 'Sales Org Not Approved', 
       VBELN,
       SPART
FROM tblVBAK
WHERE VKORG != '1001';
```